# How to display an 8x8 checkerboard?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, awt, graphics2d

I want to display an 8x8 checkerboard, but with the bellow code I only get horizontal lines with alternating colors.

```
Color color = Color.gray;
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        if (color == Color.gray)
        {
            color = Color.lightGray;
        }
        else
        {
            color = Color.gray;
        }
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(row*80, col*80, 80, 80);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*not working*"? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it produce unexpected results? Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your board columns-wise, each column going vertically.

You toggle the color for each field, not wrong.

At the end of the column, you end up with a different color than you started the column with, which is correct.

Then you toggle the color and start the next column, which means you start the next column with the same color you started the preceding one with. I.e. you always use the same color in the same line.

To solve either toggle once more after each column, or do not toggle for the first field of each column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have now added the same check (that toggles the color) in the outer for loop. Now, once it goes to a new row, it toggles the color twice, which means that I use the same color to start as the color used to end the previous row. I understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. I believe by the way, that you confused row and columnd, and/or x and y coordinates.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I meant "Now, once it goes to a new COLUMN, it toggles the color twice, which means that I use the same color to start as the color used to end the previous COLUMN."

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same pattern( means start with same color and toggle) for every vertical line.

```
BBBBBBBB
WWWWWWWW
BBBBBBBB
WWWWWWWW
BBBBBBBB
WWWWWWWW
BBBBBBBB
WWWWWWWW
```

But you need to toggle the start of every vertical line so that start of two consecutive vertical lines are not the same.

```
BWBWBWBW
WBWBWBWB
BWBWBWBW
WBWBWBWB
BWBWBWBW
WBWBWBWB
BWBWBWBW
WBWBWBWB
```

So in your code need to change the color for every row also, since after every row end color and next row start color is the same.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        if (color == Color.gray) {
          color = Color.lightGray;
        } else {
          color = Color.gray;
        }
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillRect(row * 80, col * 80, 80, 80);
      }
      if (color == Color.gray) {
        color = Color.lightGray;
      } else {
        color = Color.gray;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand your explanation. In the picture by OP, each horizontal row does in fact have different one than the previous one. The problem is that the color does not change between the fields inside a row.

Comment: Do you think that the code creates one horizontal row and the continues with the next one below? Or is it one vertical column and then the next one to the side? Be careful, OP has not consistently named counter variables....

Comment: @Yunnosch after every row end color and next row start color is not same in OP code but it need to be same, so just toggle again after end of row. Interestingly OP doing exactly same as answer. And I tested the code it's works.

Comment: Is a "row" for you horizontal (for me it is) and a column vertical (for me it is) or is it the other way round for you? Did you look at OPs picture? Your explanatin does not match what the picture shows. If you use "horizontal" and "vertical" in your explanation, then it would be helpful even if you and me disagree on the meanign of "column" and "row". As it is, your explanation reads wrong for people who agree with my understanding ot the words, they might not be half of the audience, but allow me to think that I am not alone...

Comment: @Yunnosch Picture shows the current output and currrent OP start with same color(same pattern) for every vertical line, but it need to toggle to make checkerboard

Comment: So for you "row" == "vertical" line? You should clarify that in your explanation. What is a "horizontal line" for you? A "column"? I ask because OP seems at least clear on the fact that rows and columns are at right angles. Even if I believe that OP has confused/swapped row/column and x/y. That makes it even more important to write a correspondingly clear explanation ...  not only code which works as desired.

Comment: The ASCII art you show does not match OPs image. Did you look at it?

Comment: @Yunnosch OP shows wrong image that his code produce and want `8*8` checkerbroad See [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Checkerboard_pattern.svg)

Comment: The wrong code produces what is visible in the image. Your code happens to create a checker board, but the explanation, especially including your ASCII art, discusses a different mistake.

Comment: @Yunnosch Aha understood fixed

Comment: You still use "row" differently than I expect, without explaining that you mean "vertical line".

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes that totally fine for explaining code only

Comment: @Yunnosch It's really hard to explain such a case :(

Comment: I agree. It usually helps to use more words and not rely on word being understood in one of two misunderstandable ways. If you see a potential misunderstanding, or have one pointed out to you, phrasing more carefully is better. In that case redundancy is a good thing. StackOverflow answers sometimes need to be more than code which does get the job done. Adding well-phrased explanations also helps fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this is to set the `Color` based on the value of the column index. That is, if the index is even you use one `Color`, if it is odd you use another `Color` based on the column.

```
Color color = col % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
g.setColor(color);
```

However, you will have the same problem since this will just alternate column values. When you start a new row, you will get the same Color as the column above so you see vertical columns of the same Color.

So the solution is to use both row/column index when determining the Color:

```
Color color = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
g.setColor(color);
```

Also, note that you should be use the upper case Color variables since they follow the convention for naming "static final" variables. The lower case variables only exist for backward compatibility and could be removed at any time.